# How to increment or decrease a value in a progress bar with a button

Tags: android

I am trying to make a timer from a progress bar.
In the button, I already find the way to decrease a certain value (40), but the progress does not set. After pressing the button, the bar decreases (40) but right away it resumes the old value.

Can you help, please?

```
package com.example.testeinv;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    private Button button4;

    private ProgressBar mProgressbar;
    private TextView mHelp;
    private int mProgressStatus = 0;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mProgressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    mHelp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHelp);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (mProgressStatus < 100){
                mProgressStatus++;
                android.os.SystemClock.sleep(150);
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressbar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
           mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                  mHelp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }
           });
        }
    }).start();


        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mProgressbar.setProgress(mProgressStatus - 40);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You can add this code snippet. just need to do below code on button click

```
 button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mProgressStatus = mProgressbar.getProgress()- 40;
        mProgressbar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
    }
  });
```

Comment: PLease upvote my answer if worked for you it will help others also

Answer (score 0):

It because you only set `mProgressStatus - 40` to the progress, but the real value of `mProgressStatus` is the same

Try this:

```
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mProgressStatus = mProgressStatus - 40
            mProgressbar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
        }
    });
```

About the `Thread`, it will stop after the progress reaches 100, this case when you hit the button the progress won't run any more. If this is not what you intended, use a `Timer` and `TimerTask` instead, The `Timer` will keep running until you cancel it

Comment: Thanks Tam for the fast answer, but the way that you suggested does not seam to work.
The bar doesn't even decrease the (brief 40) value like before :(

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve here?. The progress bar continues to increase to 100, hit the button will make it down by 40 and will continue increasing?

Comment: Yes. Like a potion that heals you before you die (at 100) ;)
Maybe I need to get the current value of the bar and subtract the 40?
Is that viable? How can I do it?
Thanks again!

Comment: What if progress already reached 100 and you hit the button, will it decrease by 40 and run again?

Comment: I will see the option of the Timer. Many thanks Tam :)

Comment: @RafaelLoureiro If it helps, upvote or "mark as answer" to encourage us helping more people too